# if $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x\sin x+\cos x$ then number of points where $f(x)=g(x)$?

Tags: functions, derivatives, roots

The question is if $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=x\sin x+\cos x$ then number of points where $f(x)=g(x)$?

My approach:-
$$f(x)=g(x)\implies x^2=x\sin x+\cos x\implies x^2-x\sin x-\cos x=0$$
Let $$h(x)=x^2-x\sin x-\cos x$$Now we have to find out roots of $h(x)$.
To do it I differentiate it and get the minimum point of $h(x)$ as follows:-
$$h'(x)=x(2-\cos x)=0\implies x=0 $$or
$$\cos x=2$$, which is impossible. At $x=0 $, $ h(x)=-1<0$. Now in the graph we have one information that the function is minimum on $0$, now where to go from here, what is the next step?

Comment: $h'(x)\ne 2x-x\cos x$

Comment: Try something cruder: $f(0)=0,g(0)=1$, whereas $f(\pi)=\pi^2\approx 10,g(\pi)=-1$. So $f(x)=g(x)$ for at least one value in $(0,\pi)$. Since $f(-x)=f(x),g(-x)=g(x)$, there is another root in $(-\pi,0)$.

Comment: From the graphs (y = f(x), y = g(x)) shows that the roots of the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $h(x)$ is continuous and even. We have $h(0)=-1<0$, $h(\pi)=\pi^2-1>0$, hence by the IVT there is at least one zero $x_0\in(0,\pi)$.
For $x>0$ we have $$h'(x)=2x-\sin x-x\cos x+\sin x = x\cdot(2-\cos x)>0$$
so that by Rolle there cannot be two positive zeroes. We conclude that there is exactly one positive zero, by evenness of $h$ also exactly one negative zero, hence exactly two zeroes in total.

Answer (score 1):

Equality occurs at the roots of

$$h(x):=f(x)-g(x)=x^2-x\sin(x)-\cos(x).$$

For a continuous function, the minima and maxima alternate and there is at most one root in-between, one before the first and one after the last. A root is there if the function changes sign in the corresponding interval.

Then
$$h'(x)=2x-x\cos(x)=x(2-\cos(x))$$

has a single root at $x=0$ (the other factor cannot change sign).

From

$$h(-\infty)=\infty,h(0)=-1,h(\infty)=\infty$$ we conclude that there are exactly two roots.